# How to get the 'view' name from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

There is a `'view'` create by name `'Test_View'` and a job created under `'Test_View'` is `'Test_Job'`.

```
Test_View >> Test_Job
```

In `Test_Job`, I am trying to print the `name_of_the_view` (i.e., `'Test_View'`).

How do I retrieve the `view` name in `Test_Job` ?

I don't think so, if there are any environment variables available.

Can I do it from groovy script ?

Comment: Views in Jenkins are just for organizing existing jobs. It would be helpful to know what exactly are you trying to achieve by getting a view name in `Test_Job` ...

Comment: @SiddharthKaul There are many views and each view contains many jobs again. Each view shows the graphical stats of those jobs executed. And to get hold of that, URL goes something like <URL>/view/<view-name>

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible using Jenkins UI but with the Groovy you can extract, `instance.view` will enable to read view configured into Jenkins, but that even is only possible with iteration (using for loop) for all views in Jenkins.

```
found_views = []

views = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.views

for (view in views){
  for (job in view.items) {
    if (job.name.equals(Test_Job)){
      Test_View << view.name
    } // if
  } // for view.items 
}// for view
```

Also have a look in [HERE](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-23283)